# Who first proved that $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$?

Tags: mathematics

Who first proved the interchangeability of partial derivatives? I never see any reference in textbooks. This is not a trivial result.

Comment: For analytic functions it is trivial. The problem is that the modern definition of function was only given in 19th century. Previously most mathematicians thought of "functions" as analytic functions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko What would be the contrast between the "_modern definition of function_" and "_analytic functions_"?

Comment: clairaut? schwarz? young?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks as if it was Euler who first proved it. See *[A note on the history of mixed partial derivatives](https://web.archive.org/web/20170923003138/http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=1580215&messageID=5765194)*, by Thomas James Higgins (*Scripta Mathematica* **7** (1940), pp. 59–62).

Comment: Nice paper. One might add that (according to [Euler himself](https://mathoverflow.net/a/156133)) the first to put it in anything like the notation in the title was Fontaine ([1738](https://books.google.com/books?id=8zMAAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA24), p. 26). Clairaut ([1742](http://www.archive.org/stream/histoiredelacad40laca#page/293), footnote p. 294) discusses the independence of Euler’s, Fontaine’s, and his own proof.

Comment: One might also add that [Lindelöf](https://archive.org/stream/actasocietatissc81suom#page/n223/mode/2up) in 1867 criticized all proofs that had been given so far and that the first rigorous proof was subsequently presented by [Schwarz](https://archive.org/stream/gesammeltemathem02schwuoft#page/274/mode/2up) in 1873.

Comment: José Carlos Santos link is dead? anyway what about clairaut? schwarz? young?

Comment: @BCLC: I just saw your comment while answering the MSE question [Arbitrary Mixed Partial Derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4465582/13130). I notice that the URL for José Carlos Santos's answer is for a Math Forum archived sci.math post of mine,  and those links no longer work (they might now redirect to behind a paywall, I don't know, as I'm not a NCTM member -- they purchased Math Forum a few years back, and then discontinued it for money reasons). Fortunately, [that post is also in the google sci.math archive](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/mNOiQfjVV7s/m/W-3JrY0iqhQJ).

Answer (score 5):

This question could also be asked as: Who first found an example for the not-interchangeability of partial derivatives?

It was H.A. Schwarz who proved the theorem: If a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is $m$ times differentiable *and continuous*, then the $m$th mixed derivatives are independent of the order.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused:  what's meant here by a function which is differentiable but not continuous?

Comment: For an example see for instance W. Mückenheim: "Mathematik für die ersten Semester", 4th ed., De Gruyter, Berlin 2015, p. 246 or https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Schwarz

Comment: I think you should mention notation $f \in C^m$, not for the sake of notation _per se_, but to help the person who asked the question.

Comment: I am unaware of that paper by Schwarz. I only know the one where he proved the interchangeability of the partial derivatives for a function of two variables: https://archive.org/stream/gesammeltemathem02schwuoft#page/274/mode/2up